# Laravel Carbon failed to parse time string error

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I import datas from excel with excel maatwebsite laravel to a mysql db, I dunno why but I see that in Excel date column are in text format (and only if i click ENTER inside each cell it became date format),
so the only method to import automatically them that i found is

```
 public function model(array $row)
    {
        $year_pd = Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("Y");
        $day_pd = Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("m");
        $month_pd = Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("d");
        $hour_pd = Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("H");
        $minute_pd = Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("i");
        $pickup_date = Carbon::create($year_pd, $month_pd, $day_pd, $hour_pd, $minute_pd);
        $year_dd = Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("Y");
        $day_dd = Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("m");
        $month_dd = Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("d");
        $hour_dd = Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("H");
        $minute_dd = Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("i");
        $drop_date = Carbon::create($year_dd, $month_dd, $day_dd, $hour_dd, $minute_dd);

        return new Driveme([
              'targa' => $row[14],
              'modello' => $row[13],
              'driver' => $row[10],
              'pickup_date' => $pickup_date,
              'drop_date' => $drop_date,
          
              //'pickup_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat($row[7]),
              //'drop_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat($row[8]),
          ]);
```

but at certain point importation stops and it gives me this error

> Could not parse '13/06/2021 19:00':
> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/06/2021 19:00) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

All dates have the same format, so why it stops casually on a date if they are all similar?

If I use Carbon::createFromFormat($row[7]) it tell me that format date is incorrect

Thx

Comment: 13/06/2021 is not a valid format. `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.`. It's trying to parse it as `m/d/y`, and there is no 13 month. Try using `createFromFormat` instead of `parse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, `13/06/2021` is being parsed as `m/d/Y`, due to the PHP [strtotime rules](https://www.php.net/strtotime). Other dates may appear work because the first digit is between 1-12, but you won't be getting the actual date that you want (You send 01/06/2021 expecting June 1st, but Carbon will return January 6th)). You need to pass the format into the createFromFormat function:

```
 Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $row[7]);
```